# Swift subclass of NSPoupupButton, how to get action (IBAction) within the subclass

Tags: swift, events, ibaction, first-responder

In Swift 4 I’ve subclassed NsPopupButton. I can use the control in a view and do the usual Ctrl-Drag to create an IBAction and all that works.

What I want to do is handle the action within the subclass itself, as well as allow views to respond.

I’m new to Swift/MacOS/Xcode but program in Windows using C# and understand the concepts of Target/Action and traversal of the Responder tree - but be gentle with me :) the reason for doing this is to intercept the user selecting an item and saving it for later restoration.

I tried, in the subclass, to self.target = self, and self.action = #Selector to a local function. That works, but the action/event stops traversing the responder tree, it just stops in the subclass.

So, how can I get the subclass to respond to the user changing the selection, and then let anything else respond to the action as well?

Answer (score 0):

In macOS there is a pattern called Cocoa Bindings. It can be used as a very convenient replacement for target / action.

Control-drag from the menu item of the popup button to First Responder (the read cube) of the target view controller (or class if a xib is used). If the `IBAction` is created correctly it's supposed to appear in the list. The action method is performed in the first object of the current responder chain which has implemented the method.

Comment: Hi and thanks for responding, I tried this and while I get the action called in the View, it does not get called in the subclass. So, in my subclass, in the AwakeFromNib, I've added target=self, and the action=#selector 'local method' - that works, but in the storyboard, when I ctrl-drag the control to the first responder, selecting the IBAction I've created in the viewcontroler, the view controller never gets fired. - any thoughts?